# Undefined when accessing to a viewModel object

Tags: contenteditable, knockout.js

Im trying a weird way to save the changes with a contenteditable span but I have a little problem:

This is my span:

```
<span data-bind="text: Content, event: { blur: viewModel.contentEdited}" contenteditable></span>
```

and the viewModel is like:

```
var viewModel = {
    notes: ko.observableArray([]),
    newNoteContent: ko.observable(),
    actualId: 0
};

viewModel.contentEdited = function () {
    alert(this.notes);
}
```

The template is binding to a note that is:

```
function note(id, date, content, category, color, background) {
    this.ID = id;
    this.Date = date;
    this.Content = content;
    this.Category = category;
    this.Color = color;
    this.Background = background;
}
```

the alert says "Undefined", is that because im creating another instance of the viewModel and the notes there is empty? The context of the templates is a note and that is outside the viewModel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Knockout, you need to be careful with what the value of `this` is when your methods are called.  When you are inside the items (notes), then `this` will be the array item.

The easiest way to handle this is to be explicit about the value of `this`.  Knockout includes an implementation of the `bind()` function that allows you to effectively set the value of `this` for a function.

So, your function would look like:

```
viewModel.contentEdited = function () {
    alert(this.notes);
}.bind(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thank you! So I change the "context" of 'this' when I bind to the viewModel. But If still want access to the note itself I think I could send it through a parameter or something.

Comment: Yes, you generally would want `this` to be your view model and you would want to pass in the item to act on.